# Integrate a Micro Shop in a CMS out of Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart, product-view, external

We have a Magento 1.9.3 with different store views. Now i want to integrate a Micro Shop with only a few products on a partner website.
It should show the product grid, the product detail grid and the basket in the Micro Shop, for the checkout it could be linked on our normal Shop.

I was thinking to integrate it as a iFrame, a JS overlay or as onpage php. But i dont know what's the best case to do this.

I would appreciate any hints for the best way or a Module that serve this functionality already.